# Illegal nesting: content can't be both given on the same line as %h1 and nested within it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I Work on an ecommerce website and an error in my index page and I did not find where the coprend .
Can anyone help me please ?
Thank you!

```
%h1 Products
 - if @products.present?
  %ul
   - @products.each do |product|
  %li= link_to product.name, product_path(product)
&mdash;
- if product.stock.zero?
Out of stock!
- else
= link_to 'Buy', checkout_product_path
 - else
  No products

 %a{href: new_product_path} Add product
```

my products_controlller.rb

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:checkout, :buy]

 def index
  @product = Product.all
 end

def show
 @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end...

...

 private

 def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, :price, :image_url, :stock)
 end
end
```

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate, the explanation in the linked answer applies here, but in your case the lines are the first two, you can’t have both `%h1 Products` and the content below (which is indent and so is also being seen as content of the `h1` tag.  You need to fix the indentation of the `- if @products.present?` block.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
%h1 Products
  - if @products.present?
    %ul
      - @products.each do |product|
        %li
          = link_to product.name, product_path(product)
          &mdash;
          - if product.stock.zero?
            Out of stock!
          - else
            = link_to 'Buy', checkout_product_path
  - else
    No products

  %a{href: new_product_path} Add product
```

Comment: Wouldn't that try to put the `<ul>` inside the `<h1>` (`<h1><ul>...</ul></h1>`) when it should follow it (`<h1>...</h1><ul>....</ul>`)?